# NSUncaughtException when trying to use tap recognizer on custom UIView Subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, subclass, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have several UIViews on my viewController & I would like to tap on them to take me to different view controllers. I have a custom UIView subclass for custom UIView appearances and since I was unable to navigate from the subclass I created a delegate protocol which would allow me to navigate from view controller

protocol:

```
protocol TapDelegate {
  func viewWasTapped()
}
```

On the view controller I have conformed to this protocol, created an instance of the custom subview (constant is icons) and finally I created a function to navigate to various view controllers:

```
func viewWasTapped() {
    print("icon was tapped")    

    if icons.tag == 0 {

        let food_Tabs_VC = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: FoodTabsViewController.self)) as! FoodTabsViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(food_Tabs_VC, animated: true)

    } else if icons.tag == 1 {

        let movesVC = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: MovesViewController.self)) as! MovesViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(movesVC, animated: true)
    } else if icons.tag == 2 {

        let msgLogVC = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: MsgLogViewController.self)) as! MsgLogViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(msgLogVC, animated: true)

    } else {

        let myWorldVC = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyWorldViewController.self)) as! MyWorldViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myWorldVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

However when I try to use tap gesture in my custom UIView subclass when I tap on UIView I get the error of uncaught exception , here is tap gesture code:

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController()

let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(homeVC.viewWasTapped))
self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: And what exactly the exception is? And what is exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code

```
let homeVC = HomeViewController()

let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(homeVC.viewWasTapped))
self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

look quite suspicious to me as last line implies that `self` is some subclass of `UIView`. And the target of `viewWasTapped` selector should be of type `HomeViewController`. So probably you need to change your `target` in the second line to `homeVC`.